# How to get UIView in cocos2dx, Need to add UIImagePickr

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, cocos2d-x

I have made a bridge class for calling Objective-C functions in Cocos2d-X's cpp classes.
Now I have to show ImagePicker for capturing UserPhoto.

```
// Method from testBridge class, written in C++
TestBridge::captureImage(UIView*);

// Calling it from a class derived from CCLayer
// Here problem is how to get UIView, 
// I can get CCEAGLView view = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getOpenGLView();
// Don't know how to cast UIView from CCEAGLView

TestBridge::sharedInstance()->captureImage(view);
```

In the TestBridge class I call a objective C class's method captureImage
which has the following implementation

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = sourceType;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[view addSubview:picker.view];
// I have also called presentViewController from picker, but it gives crash
```

I think I have conveyed my problem, Anyone knows anything about my problem?

Comment: I've done similar using Cocos2d-Swift. There, your Director is a View Controller, so you can get its view and add arbitrary subviews to it.

Comment: Problem is I have to do it in cocos2dx, Any idea how to do it in cocos2dx?